# Weird typescript inference with explicit JSDoc annotations

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I wrote vanilla JS with typescript style JSDoc annotations.

The inferred return type is `Promise<new (width?: number, height?: number) => HTMLImageElement>`, did I miss anything?

```js
/**
 * Load an image from a given URL
 * @param {String} url The URL of the image resource
 * @returns {Promise<Image>}
 */
export function loadImage(url) {
  /*
   * We are going to return a Promise which, when we .then
   * will give us an Image that should be fully loaded
   */
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    /*
     * Create the image that we are going to use to
     * to hold the resource
     */
    const image = new Image();
    /*
     * The Image API deals in even listeners and callbacks
     * we attach a listener for the "load" event which fires
     * when the Image has finished the network request and
     * populated the Image with data
     */
    image.addEventListener("load", () => {
      /*
       * You have to manually tell the Promise that you are
       * done dealing with asynchronous stuff and you are ready
       * for it to give anything that attached a callback
       * through .then a realized value.  We do that by calling
       * resolve and passing it the realized value
       */
      // @ts-ignore
      resolve(image);
    });
    /*
     * Setting the Image.src is what starts the networking process
     * to populate an image.  After you set it, the browser fires
     * a request to get the resource.  We attached a load listener
     * which will be called once the request finishes and we have
     * image data
     */
    image.src = url;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong return type: `@returns {Promise<Image>}`.

`Image` can't be used on his own as a type.

Take a look on `Image` declaration in TS built in types:

```js
declare var Image: {
    new(width?: number, height?: number): HTMLImageElement;
};
```

Despite the fact that `Image` is `constructor` - it is not declared as a class. Hence, you can't use it in type scope.

Using `Promise<Image>` is the same as this example:

```js
const x = 10;

type Y = x;
```

`x` is a value while `Y` is a type. You can't mix them.
You can only use `classes` and `enums` in type scope.

As you might have noticed, `Image` is a constructor which returns  `HTMLImageElement`. This type should be used in your JSDOC.

So, you have two options:

1. `@returns {Promise<InstanceType<Image>>}`
2. `@returns {Promise<HTMLImageElement>}`

Hover your mouse on `const image`, you will see that it is a `HTMLImageElement`.

Please keep in mind, you can use [typescript utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) in your jsdoc